# Cannot execute npm update when using a specific docker user

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install, fpm

I have created a php fpm containers which is associated to the host user, in this way I doesn't have any issues with the file generated within the docker container (eg: when using `php artisan make:controller`).

So I have this `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
    version: '3.9'
    
    services:
    
      laravel-fpm:
        user: 1000
        container_name: laravel_app
        restart: always
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./src:/var/www/html
```

and this is the `Dockerfile`:

```
    FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine
    WORKDIR /var/www/html
    
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
    RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
    RUN apk add icu-dev
    
    # Installa nodejs per l'utilizzo delle dipendenze npm
    RUN apk add --update npm
    RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
    RUN npm install
    
    CMD ["php-fpm"]
    
    EXPOSE 9000
```

When I access within the container `docker-exec -it laravel_app sh`, and then I run `npm install` I get:

```
Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:0 "/.npm"
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /.npm
npm ERR! errno -13
```

This problem is related to the `USER` directive which I have specified on the container, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Did you try changing fileowner as suggested in the error message?

Comment: @DanielW. I doesn't have sudo command 'cause I'm using the alpine image, and also I would like to avoid this error, so I hope that someone suggest me a solution

Comment: The command isn't `sudo` the command is `chown`

Comment: @DanielW. same, alpine image aren't shipped with those command. Anyway, I want avoid to chown each time myself and fix this in the docker file

Comment: The error message says the problem is fixed in new versions. Upgrade your npm, fix the files, and the problem is gone.

Comment: @DanielW. Well this line is supposed to install the latest version: `RUN apk add --update npm`, if so, then the problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Problem

When you're running the Docker container as uid 1000, that user doesn't exist in the container, so default paths, such as for the npm cache that would normally be in the HOME directory of the running user don't have anywhere to live, so defaults to `/`. During the build, you are acting as `root` since there is no `USER` directive. Additionally, the `npm install` inside the build is possibly creating the cache directory, but without the `package.json` has nothing to install.

## The Solution(s)

1. Create the user in your Dockerfile.
2. Change where npm is writing the cache.
3. Pre-create the directory

### Create a User

If you create the user, that assumes that it will always be the same user, but since you're setting the user in the Docker Compose this possibly isn't the best solution (what if you use a different user?). If you can reason which user you will be, then this might be the best option, using a USER directive in the Dockerfile.

### Change the npm cache location

You can use a `.npmrc` file, and set `cache=/some_dir`, or on the command line `npm install --cache=/some_dir` to change this. I'd suggest you create somewhere sensible in the root fs, something like `/npm`, then `cache=/npm/.npm`.

In your Dockerfile, it would look like this:

```
# Set the NPM cache location
RUN mkdir /npm && chmod a+rwx /npm
```

### Pre-create the directory

The simplest option is probably to just pre-create the cache directory with open permissions. The Dockerfile excerpt would be something like this:

```
...
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
# You don't need this if you haven't got the
#  application code in the build.
# RUN npm install
RUN mkdir /.npm && chmod a+rwx /.npm
...
```

If you want to persist this across containers, you could create a volume or bind mount a local folder into the container in the docker compose file.

Answer (score 1):

Most clean would be to create that user upfront and configure npms path prefix.

```sh
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm-alpine

# use the root user for the installation
USER root

# install and configure npm
RUN apk add --update --no-cache npm
RUN npm config -g set prefix /home/dev/.local/npm

# create the local user
ARG UID="1000" GID="1000"
RUN addgroup -g $GID "dev" && \
    adduser -D -G "dev" -s /bin/sh -u $UID "dev"

# switch to the local user
USER dev

# add npms bin path to PATH
ENV PATH="$PATH:/home/dev/.local/npm/bin"

# install package as user
RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you can run the following command to permanently get rid of the error.

```
$ sudo chown -R 1000:0 "/.npm"
```

*Note: As this command is running in `sudo` privileges, you may have to provide an administrative password.*

---

You can also add this command in your `Dockerfile` to avoid manually running it.

```
RUN sudo chown -R 1000:0 "/.npm"
```

Add this command before the `npm install` command.

Comment: I'm using an alpine image, how can I run sudo if I doesn't  have it within the dockerfile?

Comment: So I added: `RUN set -ex && apk --no-cache add sudo` and then: `RUN sudo chown -R ${CURRENT_UID}:0 "/.npm"` as you suggested and I got: `chown: cannot access '/.npm': No such file or directory`

Comment: Yep, you're right; it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find a good solution to this issue.

Comment: I'm trying to fix this from days, but seems there is no solutions at all

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to remove the error message...

Comment: `sudo` runs something with root privileges, there is no such thing as "sudo privileges". Apart from that nit, Docker image builds usually run as root already, so there is zero need for `sudo` there. Not everything is Ubuntu/Desktop! ;)